# Replace a repeating character in string with a growing number [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Replace a repeating character with a number and increment the value of number each time the character is replaced.

To explain it clearly:

I intend to add a comment to an array with its corresponding index.

**Input:**

```
[$[ , ,], $[ , ,]]
```

**Output:**
Replace `$` with `/**number**/`:

```
[/**1**/[ , ,], /**2**/[ , ,]]
```

Comment: I have removed syntax highlighting by using <!-- language-all: none --> tag, because there are no code for highlight. Also, reformatted input and output lines to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` replaces the first instance by default. So you can create a function that repeatedly replaces the first appearance of `'$'` with `'/**' + count + '**/'`, like so:

```
function replaceWithComment(str, char) {
    var count = 0;
    while (str.indexOf(char) > -1) {
        count++;
        str = str.replace(char, '/**' + count + '**/');
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you. I kept trying with 'for' loop which made it very complex and inconvenient.